# Delete XML node

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
        Boolean remove(String path, String S) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        File fXmlFile = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document XMLbook = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        Node root = XMLbook.getFirstChild(); //(1)
        Node book = XMLbook.getElementsByTagName("BOOK").item(0);//(2)
        NodeList chapterNodes = ((Element)book).getElementsByTagName("Chapter");
        Node subChapterNode=null;
        if(chapterNodes != null && chapterNodes.getLength() > 0) {
            Node chapterNode = chapterNodes.item(chapterNodes.getLength() - 1);
            NodeList subChapterNodes = ((Element)chapterNode).getElementsByTagName("Subchapter");
            if(subChapterNodes != null && subChapterNodes.getLength() > 0) {
                subChapterNode = subChapterNodes.item(subChapterNodes.getLength() - 1);
//            System.out.println(subChapterNode.getNodeName());
                Node toRemoveString=subChapterNode.getLastChild();
                XMLbook.removeChild(toRemoveString);    
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    };
```

I want to delete the last node `paragraph` I have, but it gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist. at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalRemoveChild(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.removeChild(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.removeChild(Unknown Source) at Books.SubChapter.remove(BookElement.java:92) at Books.Book.main(Book.java:22)
```

To mention that `System.out.println(subChapterNode.getNodeName());` prints well!! "Subchapter" So the problem is at the last two lines The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ROOT name="r">
    <TITLE>Portocalia ca zapada</TITLE>
    <AUTOR> I.C. Popovici </AUTOR>
    <AUTOR> Marin Eminescu </AUTOR>
    <BOOK name="b">
        <Chapter name="1">
            <Subchapter name="1.1">
                <paragraph>Primul paragraf!</paragraph>
                <paragraph>Al doilea paragraf.</paragraph>
                <paragraph>Al treilea paragraf</paragraph>
            </Subchapter>
            <Subchapter name="1.2"> 
                <paragraph>Primul paragraf, fata!</paragraph>
            </Subchapter>   
        </Chapter>
        <Chapter name="2">
            <Subchapter name="2.1">
                <paragraph>A fost o data ca niciodata</paragraph>
                <paragraph>o fata cu parul brunet si matasos</paragraph>
                <paragraph>Pe care o chema Alba ca Zapada.</paragraph>
            </Subchapter>
            <Subchapter name="2.2">
                <paragraph>In luna a13a ea s-a maritat.</paragraph>
            </Subchapter>
            <Subchapter name="2.3">
                <paragraph>In continuare, bineinteles</paragraph> 
                <paragraph>Am reusit!!</paragraph>
            </Subchapter>
        </Chapter>
    </BOOK>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Please avoid to name variables in uppercase. [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
Instead of `Document XMLbook = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);` please write `Document xmlBook = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);` Otherwise you confuse not only others, but even the syntax highlighter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the node you need to use the `parent node`  not the `document`.

Replace :

```
XMLbook.removeChild(toRemoveString);
```

by :

```
subChapterNode.removeChild(toRemoveString);
```